# Can a CSS custom property hold the value of another property?

Tags: css

I stumbled across [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and I was wondering if I could assign it with a value of another property within the same style:

```
.container {
    width:10px;
    --container-width: width; /*Attempting to assign the value of width to the variable*/
}
```

There is no sign that this can be done in the documentation but I could not find anything stating that it can only be assigned a value upon declaration.

Incase you were wondering why I'd want to do this:

```
.container {
    width:10px;
    --container-width: width;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 calc(var(--container-width) * 0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am not aware of any method to easily link a CSS variable to another,
I suggest you to do that kind of thing:

```css
.container {
  --container-width: 100px;
  width: var(--container-width);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 calc(var(--container-width) * 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* The below is only added to have a nice example */
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>
```

That way, both the `width` and the `box-shadow` will depend of the same CSS variable.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that AFAIK.
The obvious use is:

```
:root {
    --container-width: 40px; /* some default, if necessary */
}
.container {
    --container-width: 10px;
    width: var(--container-width);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 calc(var(--container-width) * 0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea that works is to set the value that you want to take as basis also as a custom property

```css
div {
  --container-width: 100;
  --shadow-width: calc(var(--container-width) * 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 calc(var(--shadow-width) * 1px) lightgreen;
  width: calc(var(--container-width) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--container-width) * 0.5px);
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container2 {
  --container-width: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="container2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work if the width is specified in pixels, but if it is auto or a percentage then it would not? In my layout I have the width set as a percentage of it's parent element, even the parents dimesnions are percentage based.

Comment: No, if you want to use the real width of an element, that is not derived from CSS but from the layout (as would be the case with **width: auto**, then custom properties are not the way to go.